# bag maribles and $E[x],V[x]$

Tags: statistics

A bag contains one read, two blue, three green, and four yellow balls.  A sample of three balls is taken without replacement.  Let Y be the number of yellow  balls in the sample. Find E[Y] and V[Y]

---

Formulas

$$ E[x]= \sum x*P(X=x_i)$$

and 
$$ V[x]= \sum (x-\mu)^2*P(X=x_i)$$

---

Told computer to find Variance and average  on R

N=10000 samplespace=c('r','b','b','g','g','g','y','y','y','y')

B = matrix(    ,   nrow=N, ncol=3)

%keeps tracks of yllows in each roll%

jellos =matrix(    ,   nrow=N, ncol=1) for(i in 1:N) { print(paste("i is ", i))

B[i,]=sample(samplespace,3,replace=FALSE) jellos[i]=0; for(j in 1:3) 
       {
 if(B[i,j]=='y') {
 jellos[i]=1+jellos[i] } } }

%finding average of jellos sum=0 for(i in 1:N) { sum=jellos[i]+sum; }

avg=sum/N

%finding variance of jellos sum1=0 for(i in 1:N) { sum1=(jellos[i]-avg)^2; }

v=sum1/(N-1) \end{verbatim}

v [1] 6.327244e-05
  avg [1] 1.2046 \

**getting avg** to be 1.204

**and variance** 6.327244e-05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the known formula for a hypergeometric distribution: $\def\assign{\mathop{\raise{0.1ex}:\hspace{-0.25ex}=}}Y\sim\mathcal{HG}(N\assign10,K\assign4,n\assign3)$

$${\hspace{2ex}\mathsf E(Y) ~{= n K/N \\ = 1.2}
\\\mathsf {Var}(Y) ~{= n K(N-K)(N-n)/N^2(N-1) \\ = 0.56}}$$

Your estimate of expectation is okay, but your variance is way off.

Looks like an error is in this line

> `%finding variance of jellos sum1=0 for(i in 1:N) { sum1=(jellos[i]-avg)^2; }`

Should be

`%finding variance of jellos% sum1=0; for(i in 1:N) { sum1=sum1+(jellos[i]-avg)^2; }`
`